# Show that the permutation symbol, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ can be expressed as $\det\{\delta_{k,l}\}$

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, vectors

This question relates to this [continuum mechanics online course](https://open.umich.edu/find/open-educational-resources/engineering/lectures-continuum-physics#unit-01-what-continuum-physics-about-remembering-vectors). So far it has excellent lectures and problem sets but no solutions.

> *Problem 3.*
>
> Show that the permutation symbol, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ can be expressed as:
> $$ \epsilon_{ijk} =  \begin{vmatrix}
>                             \delta_{i1} & \delta_{i2} & \delta_{i3} \\ 
>                             \delta_{j1} & \delta_{j2} & \delta_{j3} \\ 
>                             \delta_{k1} & \delta_{k2} & \delta_{k3} \\
>                        \end{vmatrix}$$

I am also posting my answer. I am working on my rigorous mathematical writing as well as the continuum mechanics, so I would appreciate feedback of my proof-writing style as well.

Comment: Your expression is correct and this answer might also be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874812/levi-civita-and-kronecker-delta-identity/1882044#1882044

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/919094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the conjecture:

$$ \epsilon_{ijk} =  \begin{vmatrix}
                            \delta_{i1} & \delta_{i2} & \delta_{i3} \\ 
                            \delta_{j1} & \delta_{j2} & \delta_{j3} \\ 
                            \delta_{k1} & \delta_{k2} & \delta_{k3} \\
                       \end{vmatrix}$$

It should be true that:

$$ \epsilon_{ijk}A_iB_jC_k =  \begin{vmatrix}
                                  \delta_{i1} & \delta_{i2} & \delta_{i3} \\ 
                                  \delta_{j1} & \delta_{j2} & \delta_{j3} \\ 
                                  \delta_{k1} & \delta_{k2} & \delta_{k3} \\
                              \end{vmatrix}A_iB_jC_k$$

We can expand the left hand side of the statement to be the following, keeping in mind that even though there are 27 permutations of $ijk$, only the following six of them are non-zero.

$$\epsilon_{ijk}A_iB_jC_k = A_1B_2C_3 + A_2B_3C_1 + A_3B_1C_2 - A_3B_2C_1 - A_2B_1C_3 - A_1B_3C_2$$

Likewise expanding the right hand side of statement:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
       \delta_{i1} & \delta_{i2} & \delta_{i3} \\ 
       \delta_{j1} & \delta_{j2} & \delta_{j3} \\ 
       \delta_{k1} & \delta_{k2} & \delta_{k3} \\
  \end{vmatrix}A_iB_jC_k = 
  (\delta_{i1}\delta_{j2}\delta_{k3} + 
  \delta_{i2}\delta_{j3}\delta_{k1} + 
  \delta_{i3}\delta_{j1}\delta_{k2} -
  \delta_{i3}\delta_{j2}\delta_{k1} -
  \delta_{i2}\delta_{j1}\delta_{k3} -
  \delta_{i1}\delta_{j3}\delta_{k2})A_iB_jC_k$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
       \delta_{i1} & \delta_{i2} & \delta_{i3} \\ 
       \delta_{j1} & \delta_{j2} & \delta_{j3} \\ 
       \delta_{k1} & \delta_{k2} & \delta_{k3} \\
  \end{vmatrix}A_iB_jC_k = 
  A_1B_2C_3 + A_2B_3C_1 + A_3B_1C_2 - A_3B_2C_1 - A_2B_1C_3 - A_1B_3C_2$$

$$\therefore$$

$$\epsilon_{ijk}A_iB_jC_k = \begin{vmatrix}
       \delta_{i1} & \delta_{i2} & \delta_{i3} \\ 
       \delta_{j1} & \delta_{j2} & \delta_{j3} \\ 
       \delta_{k1} & \delta_{k2} & \delta_{k3} \\
  \end{vmatrix}A_iB_jC_k$$

$$\epsilon_{ijk} = \begin{vmatrix}
       \delta_{i1} & \delta_{i2} & \delta_{i3} \\ 
       \delta_{j1} & \delta_{j2} & \delta_{j3} \\ 
       \delta_{k1} & \delta_{k2} & \delta_{k3} \\
  \end{vmatrix}$$

QED

Comment: It looks very clean. You should have $C_k$ at the line above last one.